# Plotly: How to set a varying marker opacity, but keep the same outline color for all markers?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plat marker where maker opacity is changed by some vector.

But marker **edge color opacity is constant**.

```
   fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=real.index, y=real['some_value'],
                             mode='markers',
                             marker={'opacity': real['another value'],
                                     'color':'green',
                                     'size':10,
                                     'line':dict(width=1,
                                                 color='rgba(165,42,42,1)')}
                            ))
```

It can be seen in plot below, that the marker edge color opacity, is changed together with color opacity of the marker filling.

My purpose is to keep line (marker edge ) opacity constant.

[image]

NOTE: this question doesn't answer the question:

[plotly.py: change line opacity, leave markers opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488894/plotly-py-change-line-opacity-leave-markers-opaque)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily [rescale a pandas series](https://machinelearningmastery.com/normalize-standardize-time-series-data-python/#:%7E:text=Normalize%20Time%20Series%20Data,range%20of%200%20and%201.&text=Where%20the%20minimum%20and%20maximum,the%20value%20x%20being%20normalized.) between 0 and 1 and use that as an argument in  `rgba(red,green,blue,opacity)` like `color='rgba(100,0,255,'+opac+')'` where `opac` is some opacity between 0 and 1 for a certain marker in your figure. The color property of the markers is unique for any `go.Scatter()`, so you'll have to add a unique trace for each point. Then, at the same time, you can set color (and opacity if you should feel so inclined) for the *outline* of the marker using `marker=dict(line=dict(color='rgba(100,0,255,1)'))`

In the figure below, I've set the outline color as 'rgba(100,0,255,1)', and the opacity of the marker fill as varying according to the logic above. This way, the highest values will appear as a completely "filled" marker:

[image]

But you can also set a more clearly defined line using, for example, `line=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', width = 2)` to get something like this:

[image]

Now you can play around with all the `rgba` arguments to find a color to your liking.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data in the form of an hourlt
np.random.seed(1234)
tseries = pd.date_range("01.01.2020", "01.04.2020", freq="H")
data = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(len(tseries), 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns=list('ABC')
df['C_scaled'] = df['C'].max()/df['C']
df['C_scaled'] = (df['C']-df['C'].min())/(df['C'].max()-df['C'].min())

df = df.sort_values(by=['C_scaled'], ascending=False)

fig=go.Figure()

for ix in df.index:
    d = df.iloc[ix]
    opac = str(d['C_scaled'])
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[d['A']], y=[d['B']], showlegend=False,
                             marker=dict(size = 14, color='rgba(100,0,255,'+opac+')',
                                         line=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', width = 2)))
                            )
    
fig.show()
```

**Edit:** Hoverinfo side-effects

Just include the following to edit the hoverinfo so that x and y values always are shown on hover to the closeset values:

```
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x")
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo = 'x+y')
```

[image]

Comment: looks GREAT. But here you provide `opac` with a loop is there is a way to provide as vector without loop? I suceeded in my example via `opacity` key, but it changes the opacity of the edge togeter with opacity of the marker filling.

Comment: @MichaelD The loop does a bunch of stuff, like adding a new trace, setting color etc, so that's not easily vectorized to my knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelD I don't know why you're getting your second error though. Alll should be fine as long as you use something like `'rgba(0,0,0,1)'`. Just make sure to set `width = 2` to make sure that the outlines are visible

Comment: @MichaelD *Issue* is a better word, I guess. `Issue 1:` Vectorization. `Issue 2:` "but it changes the opacity of the edge togeter with opacity of the marker filling"

Comment: @MichaelD So, how did things work out for you in the end?

Comment: I tried you solution, it's fine. But there is a **side effect** it adds all points to "hover box plot" instead of only closest point to the "mouse".

Comment: @MichaelD All good cures have side effects =) But maybe we can fix that too...

Comment: @MichaelD I often use `fig.update_layout(hovermode="x")`

Comment: @MichaelD I included a fix of the side-effects in an edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219597/discussion-between-michael-d-and-vestland).

Comment: Is there any way of adding a continuous color legend to describe what the change in opacity represents?