# Plotly line opacity with plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly, opacity

I am doing some line plots with `plotly.express`. As MWE we can consider any of the examples in the documentation, for example [this one](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plots-with-column-encoding-color) which is:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country', facet_row='country')
fig.show()
```

How would you change the opacity of the lines, without altering their color or any other of their properties?

I have tried to use `fig.update_traces(line=dict(width=1, opacity=.4))`, the `width` property works but `opacity` raises an error.

In the past with `plotly.graph_objects` I have used the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50488894/8849755) but this requires me to choose the color, this time I want `plotly.express` to do that for me. So I don't know the color of each trace.

Comment: What error are you getting? For me it works to add the line `fig.update_traces(opacity=0.5)` before `fig.show()`

Comment: Okay, I see that for the opacity its without the `line=dict(opacity=.5)`, as opposed to the width in which case the `line=dict(width=1)` seems to be required. So the full solution in my case is to use `fig.update_traces(line=dict(width=1), opacity=.1)`.

Answer (score 11):

More than a year later I ended up with the same issue, and Google brought me here. Posting here the solution for quick reference:

```py
fig.update_traces(opacity=.4)
```